# How to use PythonVirtualenvOperator in airflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

Basically I'm working with airflow and developed a task that my download a file from an external source.

```
t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='download',
        python_callable=download,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag)
```

and this airflow is running in a virtual environment (pipenv).

The download function is:

```
def download(**kwargs):
   folder_id = 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx'
   file_name = download_file(folder_id)
   return file_name
```

so basically I'm using Xcons to pass data from one task to another...and using this configurations it's impossible to manage all of dependencies of each DAG...

In the documentation I found this class called "PythonVirtualenvOperator", so to implement that I wrote :

```
t1 = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id='download',
        python_callable=download,
        requirements=['requests'],
        python_version='3.8',
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )
```

and its giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
```

the download_file function it's an API connection that is in another file.

any suggestion how can I manage the environment and have connection between tasks?

Comment: What is the `download_file` function? Can you post your entire DAG for us to help you

Comment: The download_file function it's an API connection that is in another file.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is

> provide_context=True,

Airflow cannot pickle the context because of all the unserializable stuff in it. You can use templating and `op_kwargs` to work around this if you only need simple stuff like `execution_ts`:

```
t1 = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id='download',
        python_callable=download,
        provide_context=False,
        op_kwargs={
          execution_date_str: '{{ execution_date }}',
        },
        dag=dag)
```

Of course, you will need to update the arguments to your callable. I didn't go any deeper than that because it worked for my use case.

Comment: op_kwargs is not valid dictionary in the example you provided. please provide minimum working solution.

Comment: I changed the = to a :.

Comment: how about python_callable method as he should not use **kwargs but args relating to op_kwargs dict keys.

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of the [PythonVirtualenvOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/566127308f283e2eff29e8a7fbfb01f17a1cd18a/airflow/operators/python.py#L218-L231):

```
The function must be defined using def, and not be
part of a class. All imports must happen inside the function
and no variables outside of the scope may be referenced.
```

I'm guessing that someplace in the chain of code that's being called in your `download` function, there's a method that's imported from another file using a top-level import.  Perhaps moving that import into your `download` function is enough?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the best way is to use my class "download" as a module to be installed in the virtual operator.

Comment: Hi @YaroslavKolodiy, I am facing an issue with PythonVirtualenvOperator where the task is not using mention packages and mentioned python version insdie the task. It's looks like operator just skipping the option and using default python version n libraries present in the server where airflow is installed. Can you provide some suggestion on this to me.

Comment: Hi @Pelab I resolved my problem using containerization, I decided to migrate all of my tasks to DockerOperator that have the scripts and dependencies already installed.

Comment: @Pelab if you want to user the PythonVirtualenvOperator verify if you are creating correctly the task [doc](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d4c4492a10f5e269f80067b724aa2c345bf97ee0/airflow/operators/python.py#L361)